# What is this icon in my taskbar (green arrow on white gear with green background)

Tags: icons, taskbar

[image]

Nothing happens if I hover over or click on it.  Here's my entire taskbar:

[image]

Comment: What set of icons are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  I've updated the question with my entire taskbar.

Comment: It seems like it's an update (available) icon. Maybe from Ubuntu itself, or other application, it would be necessary to find out which is it.

Comment: "it would be necessary to find out which is it." -- this is what I'm asking!!!!!!

Comment: Yes, I understand, but as I stated, it appears to be an **update** icon, so if I'm right, you can *narrow it down* to, for example "software updates".

Comment: You can look also for example in autostart applications for some "update" app.